# How to get temporary filename when use OpenFileDialog in C# Winform

Tags: c#

In C#-WinForms I use a `OpenFileDialog`. I want to get all files/filenames in a selected folder, without pressing the ok button of the `OpenFileDialog`.

Is there a good way to achieve this?

Comment: It's strange to get the (not by the user confirmed) selected filename. Probably not.

Comment: Really, Any way ?

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to so! Can you please consider editing your question so that it is easier for people to answer, perhaps providing some code you have already tried and is not working for example. At the moment I don't think your question is clear enough to answer.

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your code. Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.

Comment: I am sorry if my question is not understood with everybody. Really, I want to get all file names when I click on one folder but I dont still press button OK ?

Comment: What "code example" do you expect in this situation? Code reading the files after they have been selected? The OP is asking how to read the filenames before the users hits the "ok" button.

Comment: It is a dialog, it won't complete and won't tell you what was selected until you click OK.  Necessarily so, a selected file can be unselected again.  So what you want is not in the cards.  It has a FileOk event that fires early when the user selects a file, it is meant to prevent selection.  Whether that is what you want is not at all clear from the question.

Comment: OpenFile dialog asks you to select or enter a file name-What do you want?

Comment: When I select folder but not press button OK

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question in the right way, you want to get the Filenames out of your selected folder. To archive that, you could use a [FolderBrowserDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
if(folderBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   var path = folderBrowser.SelectedPath;
   System.Windows.IO.DirectoryInfo info = new System.Windows.IO.DirectoryInfo(path);
   foreach(var file in info.GetFiles())
   {
       //do what you want with your files.
       //example
       listbox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
   }
 }
```

If you got some further question, feel free to ask.

-- EDIT --

Ok now i understood what you mean.

You want to get the files out of a folder when clicking on it. 
Maybe build your own dialog (simple new window). With a treeview on it. And if you click on a treeviewitem, on ther other side it displays you the files and subfolder.

[image]

Comment: Hi Hendrik, All dialogs return selected path after click on button OK. But I want to get name selected path before click on button OK

Comment: The easiest way would be to create a new dialog your self as i mentoined in my edit. Just create a new Window with a treeview oder maybe two treeviews. One on the left the other one on the right, same like windows explorer layout.